# Getting country from jVectormap onregionclick

Tags: onclick, jvectormap

I'm trying to learn jVectormap and I'm stuck trying to return the country when clicked on. Is there any way to convert the code into a country, or just get the country when clicking on the map?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#world-map').vectorMap ({
            onRegionClick: function (e, code) {
                console.log (code);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here ya go

```
onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
     var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
     var name = map.getRegionName(code);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
onRegionClick:function(event, code){              
                          var name = (code);                          
                                window.location.href("http://your url address"+ code);
                          }
```

change the "your url adress" to your link address.

All script

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
          onRegionClick:function(event, code){            
              var name = (code);                          
                window.location.href("http://your url address"+ code);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```